# why can't we have two main verbs in a sentence in syntax

Tags: syntax, historical-linguistics, verbs

Would you please exlain to me why can't we have two main verbs in a sentence in syntax?

Thank you so much

Comment: Are you asking for a technical explanation in terms of Merge?

Comment: This question puzzles and perplexes me.

Comment: If you define a sentence as a sequence of words that begins with a capital letter and ends with a full stop, then it is possible (indeed common) for there to be two 'main' verbs  This typically occurs in coordination constructions, e.g. [Liz **drove** to the shops] [and Ed **walked** to the pub]. The bracketed elements are main (independent) clauses within a single sentence, each with its own 'main' verb.

Comment: As many others have pointed out, it's perfectly possible to have two main verbs in a sentence, but I think what you mean is why we can't have two main verbs in a *clause* or in an *intonational unit*, which may be a potentially interesting question about the historical development of English. Perhaps you could modify your post this way?

Comment: (ignore the 'intonation unit' part in the previous post, I wasn't thinking straight)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Making this an answer so that I can include images; I can't do that in a comment.)

"In syntax" is pretty vague: there are many different theories of how English syntax works. But in all the ones I've ever heard of, you can coordinate two VPs to get a new VP.

[image: sample tree]

Some theories only allow binary branching, in which case you have to add an extra level of indirection:

[image: another tree]

And there are various arguments about why one of these ways is better than another. But I don't know of any theory that doesn't allow combining two VPs into a conjoined VP with a conjunction.

(Depending which theory you're using, your trees may not look like this: the root might be a TP or an IP, for example, instead of an S. But I'm going with the simplest model I can think of to show off the bits that are important.)

Comment: There's also `He sang, and then it rained, until the police arrived, whereupon...`

Comment: @Draconis I'm pretty sure you are excused by default for making this an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: As much as *hit and run* is a single noun, there is only one VP "sing and dance". There was a thread recently concluding that word boundaries are fuzzy. I had thought syntax theories put VP as the root, perhaps for the reason in question.

Comment: I'd say that "He [sang] [and danced]" contains a coordination of two VPs. I suppose one could say that "sang" and "danced" are 'main verbs', but it's a pretty meaningless term here.

Comment: For a recent paper arguing against VP coordination, see the third section of this:
Cacoullos, R. T., & Travis, C. E. (2019). Variationist typology: Shared probabilistic constraints across (non-) null subject languages. *Linguistics*, 57(3), 653-692.

Comment: @WavesWashSands Interesting; I can't access that until I get back on campus (and have library access), but what do those authors say about "he sang and danced"?

Comment: @Draconis: Basically these are no different from regular zero anaphora. The key data is from Figure 5 (https://i.imgur.com/GrIWRMy.png): they find around 80%, 50%, 50%, 30% occurrence of zero anaphora in sentences where the two verbs are syntactically (i.e. with a coordinating conjunction) and prosodically linked, syntactically but not prosodically linked, prosodically but not syntactically linked, and unlinked, respectively. There is no categorical behaviour in any of these contexts and a similar situation obtains in Spanish (~90%, 80%, 80%, 60%). So there is no reason to treat VP

Comment: coordination as different from any kind of zero anaphora. (BTW, have you tried your school's proxy server or VPN, if your school has these?)

Comment: @Draconis it is freely available online https://www.academia.edu/21701877/Variationist_typology_Shared_probabilistic_constraints_across_non-_null_subject_languages

Comment: Also, the claim in Cacoullos & Travis 2019 is that "VP Coordination must be abandoned both as a discrete category and as a property of **English** that sets it apart as a non-null subject language" [emphasis mine - Alex B.].

Comment: @AlexB. I thought that the argument was restricted to English was obvious since the question is about English, but thanks for clarifying the point!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's perfectly possible to have more than one verb in the same clause: He drank, ate, went to bed, slept well.
What is really impossible is to have more than one verb with more than one subject. I think clauses like: "the dog, the cat, the horse growled, purred, whinnied" are impossible in all natural languages. This is computer syntax. A clause like "the dog, the cat, the horse growled, purred, whinnied" must be unzipped into three simple clauses in natural languages.

Comment: Thank you. But, for example, how would someone prove the ungrammaticality of: we like traveling running.

Comment: Not just verbs but also it didn’t work for nouns or Determiners. For example, why cannot we say the that of book table. Will those be fighting for the same place since they are from the same category ??

Comment: Yes, pretty much: English only allows one determiner per noun phrase, and it also doesn't allow [serial verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_verb_construction). That's just an English thing, other languages do: for instance, I'll say "il mio cane" for "my dog" in Italian, but in English \*"the my dog" wouldn't be acceptable, with both words taking up the same slot. As to serial verbs, the Wikipedia article I linked provides example.
But, this isn't really the same question as whether you can have two main verbs in the same sentence: you *can*, as others said, but you need a connective.